# ¿ Como centrar horizontalmente y espaciadamente varios elementos dentro de un <div>?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo dentro de un `<div>` varios elementos `<span>`, `<button>` y `<img>` alineados horizontalmente.

Necesito que estén centrados verticalmente. Deben estar entre ellos alineados horizontalmente y espaciadamente ocupando el 100% del `<div>`.

Al hacer mas pequeña la ventana del navegador los 3 primeros elementos deben alinearse verticalmente y el elemento 4 debe permanecer alineado horizontalmente a los 3

El código que tengo me lo centra verticalmente pero no consigo que los elementos se coloquen equitativamente en espaciado horizontal. Tampoco se como hacer que los primeros 3 elementos se me coloquen verticalmente en caso que la ventana del navegador se haga mas pequeña.

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items; center;"
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <span class="t1">Elemento1</span>
    <span class="t2">Elemento2</span>
    <button class="b1">Elemento3</button>
    <img class="i1">Elemento4</img>
</div>
```

Comment: primero que todo tienes una etiqueta **img** mal estructurada, segundo a que tamaño de ancho **(width)** quieres que se acomoden los 3 elementos vertical y el 4 horizontal?

Comment: Me interesaría que el Width de los 3 elementos en vertical fuera del 50% y para el 4 el restante 50%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `justify-content: space-around;` para alinearlo horizontalmente ocupando todo el espacio. Y para alinearlo verticalmente los elementos en resoluciones chicas, puedes utilizar `flex-direction: column;`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  /* muestra elementos con la misma separación alrededor de ellos */
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* alinea los elementos verticalmente */
  align-items: center;
}

/* media query para mobile */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #container {
    /* cambio la dirección de los elementos*/
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <span class="t1">Elemento1</span>
    <span class="t2">Elemento2</span>
    <button class="b1">Elemento3</button>
    <img class="i1" src="https://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" />
</div>
```

---

#### Nota

Te recomiendo que veas cómo se usan bien todos los elementos de `flex` antes de que empieces con esto, te dejo [este link](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#es) que es para que puedas entender fácilmente como funcionan todas las propiedades.

Comment: Genial ! Me coloca todos en vertical en caso que la ventana se hace mas pequeña. Pero como se haría para que solo me pusiera en vertical los tres primeros elementos y el ultimo estuviera en horizontal respecto a los 3 en vertical.

Comment: ¿Los primeros 3 en vertical y el 4to en horizontal para resoluciones más pequeñas? Deberías envolver esos primeros 3 en un `<div>` y luego agregarle las propiedades. Si me lo confirmás, edito la respuesta.

Comment: Te lo confirmo es asi

Comment: En Firefox al hacer mas pequeña la ventana de navegación me cambia el tamaño de la imagen a mas pequeño hasta que llega a desaparecer si sigo haciendo mas pequeña la ventana.

Comment: Solucione el tema alfinal como me comentastes con otro div envolviendo los 3 elementos. Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
/*Para alinear en vertical cuando se haga pequeña la ventana*/

#container span,#container button,#container img{
    display: inline-block;
    width:20%;
}
```

Para un mejor trabajo con estilos, mejor utilizar un framework, ejemplo [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com)